# Show Order Comments on Invoice

Tags: magento2.2.6

I'm trying to get the order comment history to show on the invoice PDF.
My set up is as follows:
`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

`app/code/Denial/InvoiceComments/Model/Rewrite/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;

class Invoice extends AbstractPdf
{

    /**
 * Return PDF document
 *
 * @param array|Collection $invoices
 * @return \Zend_Pdf
 */
public function getPdf($invoices = [])
{
   echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();        
   $this->_beforeGetPdf();
    $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }
        $page = $this->newPage();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
         foreach ($_entity->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status){
         $textChunk = wordwrap($status->getComment(), 120, "\n");
         foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
            if ($textLine!=='') {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
            }
        }
    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}

}
```

However I'm getting this error:
`Fatal error: Class 'Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf' not found in /home/denialuk/public_html/magento2/app/code/Denial/InvoiceComments/Model/Rewrite/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php on line 10`
What silly little mistake have I made, because I can't see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line of code:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf;
```

Now your code looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Denial\InvoiceComments\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf;

class Invoice extends AbstractPdf
{

    /**
 * Return PDF document
 *
 * @param array|Collection $invoices
 * @return \Zend_Pdf
 */
public function getPdf($invoices = [])
{
   echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();        
   $this->_beforeGetPdf();
    $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }
        $page = $this->newPage();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
         foreach ($_entity->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status){
         $textChunk = wordwrap($status->getComment(), 120, "\n");
         foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
            if ($textLine!=='') {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
            }
        }
    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}

}
```